# A-Frame: Disable <a-sky> in AR mode

Tags: aframe

I'm a beginner with A-Frame, so not sure if I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm trying to create a scene that has a skybox for VR mode, but doesn't for AR. How can I tag the  element, so it doesn't show up in AR mode?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this functionally might be built-in eventually.

See: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/4356

In the meantime, the same link provides some code to achieve this. Taken directly from the above link (all credit to https://github.com/klausw), you would include the following script in your head:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('hide-in-ar-mode', {
    // Set this object invisible while in AR mode.
    init: function () {
        this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('enter-vr', (ev) => {
            this.wasVisible = this.el.getAttribute('visible');
            if (this.el.sceneEl.is('ar-mode')) {
                this.el.setAttribute('visible', false);
            }
        });
        this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('exit-vr', (ev) => {
            if (this.wasVisible) this.el.setAttribute('visible', true);
        });
    }
});
```

Then just modify your sky element to include `hide-in-ar-mode`, e.g.

```
<a-sky src='#sky' hide-in-ar-mode></a-sky>
```

You can also find this functionality demonstrated here: https://xr-spinosaurus.glitch.me/

Comment: This should by market by @johannes-ambrosch as the correct answer.